# Remove = from formula vba

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is  that i have an excel file where  sometimes a "=" is at the beginning of a cell making it a formula for excel.
How can i search for those cells and remove the "="?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want any formula on the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work smoothly and delete all of your "=" in sheet and keep formula visible :

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Left(cell.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then

    Else
        cell.Formula = "'" & Right(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1)
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Use `Mid(cell.Formula, 2)` instead of `Right(..,Len()-1)`. The mid function returns the remaining string when the length parameter is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
For Each c in Sheet1.Range("A1:C5").Cells
    If Left(c.Formula,1) = "=" Then c.Formula = "'" & c.Formula
Next
```

Note: above code changes formula to text ;)

```
A1 => '=Bla bla bla
```